# Error en dispositivos Samsung android.widget.Editor.performLongClick Android Java

Tags: java, android, samsung

Tengo un campo `AutoCompleteTextView`

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/input_url"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoFullscreen"
    android:inputType="textUri|textWebEditText"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:textIsSelectable="true" />
```

Inicialmente no tiene el foco

- pulsación recibe el foco
- pulsación larga, arroja el error

Error al detectar pulsación larga sobre el elemento sin foco

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.show()' on a null object reference
    at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:1216)
    at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:12779)
    at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:6992)
    at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:26176)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Lo curioso de los dispositivos que tengo para hacer pruebas solo los dos **dispositivos Samsung** se ven afectados, el motorola y el pop4 funcionan perfectamente.

Hay alguna manera de solucionar ese error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He descubierto diferentes formas de solventar el problema:

Mediante XML se puede desactivar la pulsación larga

```
android:longClickable="false"
```

En Java se puede iniciar un listener de `OnLongClick`

```
autoCompleteTv.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

> Pero también se evita que se muestre el dialogo de opciones de copiado
>   (copy,paste,selección de texto)

Si se quiere permitir que se muestre el dialogo de opciones de copiado

```
autoCompleteTv.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        autoCompleteTv.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }
});
```